# Page number url pagination CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, pagination

I use pagination CodeIgniter. I want to remove page number from url or show page number 1,2,3 not 5,10,15. How can I do that please help me I'm beginner at CodeIgniter.
Thanks

**Here is my action inside my controller**

```
class Wiki_egypt extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model('Tours_model');
        $this->load->model('Wiki_egypt_model');
        $this->load->model('Meta_model');
        $this->load->library("pagination");
    }   



    public function Wikipedia_egypt() {
        $config = array();
        
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "/wikipedia-egypt";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Wiki_egypt_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 5;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        
        
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
        
        $data["wikis"] = $this->Wiki_egypt_model->
            fetch_departments($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['meta_tags'] =  $this->Meta_model->meta_wikis_eg();
        
        $this->load->view("Header", $data);
        $this->load->view("Nav", $data);
        $this->load->view("wiki_egypt/wikieg", $data);
        $this->load->view("Footer");
    }
 }
```

**Here is my action inside my Model**

```
public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all("wiki_egypt");
}
public function fetch_departments($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC')->get("wiki_egypt");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Here is my action inside my View**

```
<?php echo $links; ?>

<?php
foreach($wikis as $row)
 {
?>

<?php  
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need another config there:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Then you need to change the way your page variable works.

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 1;
$page = $config['per_page'] * $page;
```

So now you're saying that your offset will be equal to the url page times the offset.

All the rest should work just the same.

Comment: Thanks, when I move from page 1 to page 2 its ok, but when I move from any page else except page 1 still count 10, 15, 20 at URL. It solved at the first page only.

Comment: That's odd, you might have something else changing your pagination because the docs say: $config[‘use_page_numbers’] = TRUE;

By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.  More info here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination#customizing-the-pagination